# Firebase object firebaseAuth.SigninwithemailandPassword giving nullpointerException?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm developing a hotel management app . i've recently created admin id and password login page and im using firebase database for my project.
When i click on the login button firebaseAuth.signinwithemailandpassword or firwebaseAuth.createuserwithemailandpassword throws nullpointer exception .
i've been figuring out how to solve this but unable to fin its solution .
help please.
My code is as follows:

```
 private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

in OncreateMethod : 

 firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


public void onClick(View view)
    {
        validate();

        validateUser();
    }

    public void validate()
    {

        Adminid = AdminID.getText().toString();
        Pass=Password.getText().toString();

       if(Pass.isEmpty() || Pass.contains(" "))
       {
           Password.setError("Invalid Password");
       }
       else if(Adminid.isEmpty() || Adminid.contains(" ") || !Adminid.contains("@"))
       {
           AdminID.setError("Invalid Admin ID");
       }
       else
       {
           validateUser();
       }
    }

public void validateUser()

    {

        verifylogin.setMessage("Verifying, Please Wait");
        verifylogin.show();
         firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Adminid,Pass).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
            {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    verifylogin.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, i see your code but i do not find any visible error. So I suggest, check in your firebase console if your project have enable Email/password, this is in Authentication>Access Method and you can verify that, if don´t enable only do click on pencil to edit it. Please tell me if this works.

P.S. In onClick method you call validateUser(); and validate() but inner validate() you call it too (validateUser();) just say.

Comment: sorry i was figuring out the solution so thats why i've commented the validateuser() in onclick method and called it in validate

Comment: I've also enabled the email password access in the console of firebase. still error occurs i dont know why ?

Comment: I'VE DEBUGGED THE APP AND FOUND ZZMDA zzmdc and zzmde NULL is this the problem due to which nullpointer occurs ?